# Are MacOS sparsebundles suitable for multiuser access

Tags: mac-osx, network-share, network-attached-storage, sparse-files

I want to use a sparsebundle on a linux bases NAS (synology) as a encrypted container.
The sparsebundle files will be accessible in a shared Folder via SMB or AFP for MacOS Clients.
Does this work, if potentially multiple users access the sparsebundle the same time from their MacOS Clients?

Comment: No. Even if the container files supported this, the filesystem inside is not set up for multiple access, and the different clients would write inconsistent changes and get you a corrupt volume.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Any other idea, where the encryption is done on clientside?